# How can I explain hundreds page in this topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-answer

How can I explain hundreds page of the path of purification chapter XIV, XV, XVI, XVII, some part of chapter I&III, and Abhidhamma knowledge to @dhammadhatu?

I think he asked the reason to number saṇkhāra. And I answered by the method to number saṇkhāra with source and example. What I was wrong?

https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/30171/10100

[image]

Comment: Trying to make ducks out of chicken... Your family, relatives... worthy to think about it, as a matter of gati, agati.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to explain (summarise) your answer in comments ... starting [here](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/30162/why-is-the-pali-word-sa%e1%b9%85kh%c4%81r%c4%81-in-dependent-origination-plural/30171#comment51505_30171).

I guess one might need to "chat" with DD ... and/or try to summarise (in your own words) whatever you link to ... summarise, quote from, and explain (in your own words) how or why what you're quoting and referencing is relevant to (i.e. is an answer to) the OP's question ... which (a summary) isn't always easy to write.